# RFC or something for choosing private ethernet MAC addresses?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, ethernet

for virtualization purposes I want to assign all my VM ethernet cards an individual static MAC-address. This way it is easier for me to manage DHCP.

Normally ESXi Server chooses an address with this prefix: 00:50:56
But I don't want to use this prefix to don't get problems with later/other auto generated MACs or later joining VMs.

The VMs are only connected via NAT to the Internet, so the MAC will stay private.

Is there a guideline which MAC to choose?
Something like a private MAC address space?
Or should I just choose a random one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out, that in newer versions of ESXi Server / VMWare dynamic assigned MAC addresses will start with 00:0c:29.

In older versions and when MACs are static assigned, they will start with 00:50:56. So it is secure to choose the 00:50:56 prefix when I can be sure not to use older and newer VMs at the same time.

http://communities.vmware.com/message/55378

Answer (score 0):

Lots of information here.  Creating your own MAC addresses can lead to conflict, but if they are only private, it should not cause you too much issue.  How to modify the MAC for your particular Virtualization technology is of course not addressed here.

[Wikipedia MAC Address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)